# Keeping my body and menu centered together

Tags: html, css, menu, center

I need to center this menu so when the browser is being sized it doesn't "uncenter" with the body. I've been trying to figure this out and it has just stumped me. I need the body and menu to stay together, when the browser is being sized, and always stay centered together.

html-

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="KJ's Ski Store Home.html"><img src="Ski Store Logo.png" alt="logo" height="85"            width="85"/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="KJ's Ski Store Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="KJ's Ski Store Home.html">Store</a>
    <ul id="subnav">
    <li><a href="snowboards.html">Snowboards</a></li>
    <li><a href="boots.html">Boots</a></li>
    <li><a href="helmets.html">Helmets/Hats</a></li>
    <li><a href="goggles.html">Goggles</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="location.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
div style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-left: 5%;">
<img alt="slide" src="slideshow1.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400"/>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 15%;"></div>
<div id="battle" style="float: left; width: 40%;">
<h1>Snowboarding or Skiing</h1>
<p> "<strong>Snowboarding has been better than skiing since it was invented</strong> and   nothing has changed
with that in the last, roughly, 30 years. Skiers and snowboarders get along these days, 
share the slopes and even ride together, but snowboarding is still a superior sport. It's
mellow that you followed us into the world of freestyle riding and we're happy to share 
our terrain parks and half pipes with you. We even let you hit our jibs. We don't mind 
that skiers rode our coattails into the X Games and now even the Olympics (I'm talking 
freestyle skiing here.) We're totally down with you guys and gals even if you are 
two-plankers. Nevertheless, snowboarding will always be on top."</p>
<h4>Brad Farmer, Fuel T.V.</h4>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 20px 50px 150px;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
}

ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #555;
color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
background: #555; 
display: block; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
#nav a:link{
color: #000000;
}
#nav a:visited{
color: #000000;
}
#nav a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
}
#nav a:active{
color: #000000
}
#nav a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav a:link{
color: #ffffff;
}
#subnav a:visited{
color: #ffffff;
}
#subnav a:hover{
color: #ffffff;
}
#subnav a:active{
color: #ffffff;
}

ul{ 
display: inline-flex; 
}


#logo{
text-align: center;
}

#battle h1{
text-align: center;
}
#battle p{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: did you try margin: 0 auto; in the body css?

Comment: How's this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499187/centering-my-body-to-the-menu-and-the-rest-of-the-page?

Comment: the margin: 0 auto didn't work... and I edited the last question. I really needed this done, and I know that if I just posted one again it would help it get answered sooner.

Comment: if you set your outercontainer (( body )) to a set width, it will stay centered with everything else

Comment: That worked, but now whenever you change the size of the browser it adds a lot of extra white space to the right. Is there a way to fix that? I made it 1000 px and tried using a percentage but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to learn how to indent your code properly, if you showed a bit more effort in your own work, people may be more willing to help

Comment: well currently your background is only white so not sure what you mean by added white space. You can always float everything left if your trying to keep everything to size.

Comment: @Pete my code isn't indented correctly because when I entered the code into the question box it told me it all had to be four spaces away. Thank you.

Comment: @Keith the whitespace I'm talking about is the extra stuff on the side. It's empty but wasn't the same size on each side. That's really what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'float:left;' on the items you are trying to center. You need them centered not on the left. remove that and put margin: auto; on them. http://jsfiddle.net/6q3QG/1/

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
```